# Initializing list within single line

Tags: java

I am using multimap as shown below but as shown but the issue with this that first i am adding the contents in
listand then associating it with the key, can I do it in a single line itself.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> multimap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
someList.add("abc");
someList.add("def");
someList.add("ght");
multimap.put(1, someList);
```

that is adding list contents where I am eneterting the key. something like

```
 multimap.put(1, // adding the list in a single line here itslef );
```

Comment: You could, but it is not necessarily pretty to look at. You could technically write your whole java program on one line.

Comment: Multimap is different from HashMap. You are using HashMap/.

Comment: Deja vu. I've seen that code somewhere. @Nambari FYI a multimap is essentially a `Map` with a `List` as a value.

Comment: @AdamArold: Agree, "I am using multimap" based on this wording I thought OP trying to use one of the multimap implementations.

Answer (score 4):

It's not very pretty, but you could do something along the lines of

```
multimap.put(1, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ght")));
```

Comment: Although not pretty, it's what the OP asked for

Comment: You don't need to construct an `ArrayList` from the list returned by `Arrays.asList`; just use the return value directly. All the map requires is some sort of `List`.

Comment: @TedHopp That will put an immutable List inside the map. I'd wager that the lists will get more content in the future.

Comment: @TedHopp yes, but list that is returned with `asList` has its limits like you cant add or remove its elements, so ArrayList may be better option here.

Answer (score 2):

Have a try with following code:

```
multimap.put(1, Arrays.asList(new String[]{"abc","def","ght"}));
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly create a `String[]`; `Arrays.asList` takes a varargs parameter, so simply listing the strings as arguments works: `Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ght")`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
List<String> someList = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ght");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing [Guavas Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) by hand, I recommend you to look at the Guava solution.

```
Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = HashMultimap.create();
multimap.putAll(1, Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c"));
```

This [article](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.ch/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html) nicely explains some of the advantages of the Guava Multimap implementation.

While we're at it, guava also provides a solution to initialize lists on one line ([javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html)):

```
Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> multimap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
```

Then

```
multimap.put(1, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ght")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> singletonMap = Collections.singletonMap(Integer.valueOf(1), Arrays.asList("abc", "dd", "dde"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
multimap.put(1,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("element","element")));
```